# TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments (python)

Tags: python

I made the left file to import from right 
but I don't know why I got this error: [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9mR8.png)

Comment: Post your code in your question with proper format so we can copy and paste it. Don't post an image of code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `__int__`, use `__init__`.

The [Python class tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) is a good syntax reference.

Comment: ty for helpThanks for help 
The error was in __init__
Instead of __int__